# Mozilla not starting while running selenium test from Nunit

Tags: firefox, selenium, nunit

I am using *selenium-dotnet-2.45.0*, *selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0* and Mozilla firefox-35.0.1 and *using Visual Studio IDE*
and 
as soon as I click on Run in *NUnit*, *Firefox* opens with a blank screen as shown in attached screenshot and *NUnit* blanks out and kind of hangs not showing any log/result/warning/error . I have to ultimately kill it through Task Manager.[image: Firefox as it opens on clicking on *Run* in NUnit]

Can someone help solve/troubleshoot?
Is there any issue with the versions? Thanks in advance.[image: Firefox as it opens on clicking on 'Run' in NUnit]

Comment: @Saifur This question is not a duplicate anymore, the browser version cause stated had already been sorted out, Kindly remove the duplicate tag and help me sort it out. Thanks.

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question. But, unfortunately this needs 4 more votes to reopen since it's already marked as duplicate. However, are you using Selenium-RC?

Comment: @Saifur yeah I am using Selenium Server here and not Webdriver.